# Can't access my ddwrt router web interface from local wired connection

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt

I'm facing a weird issue:
I can't access my ddwrt router web interface (192.168.1.1) from local wired connection, but I do can access it from a wifi connection (in the same subnet). Also, I can access my router web interface through a predefined DDNS address and I can't SSH to 192.168.1.1 from my local wired connection (Windows error 10061).
What I've checked/done so far:
1. Checked that there are no Firewall rules blocking.
2. Checked that there are no problematic records in 'hosts' file.
3. Removed a VPN client (Purevpn).
and as you guess - nothing helped.

Any suggestions? Because I'm clueless..

Comment: What devices do you have on your network and how are they connected? What is the wired connection wired to? The router you're trying to access or some other device?

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, it was a VLAN Misconfiguration with VMware - I'v reset the VMware virtual network/s to default, and the problem has resolved from itself.

Answer (score 0):

Please would you share your IP address information from your workstation?
Is it possible that you're connected to a different network when you're 'wired'?

Answer (score 0):

**VLAN Misconfiguration**
The symptoms you describe make it sound like the bridge that 'connects' the switch (wired) ports and the wireless clients is mis-configured or disabled.

On a PC that can access the router's web portal, go to the VLAN configuration page and check that the configuration is similar to the image below (from my dd-wrt router; default VLAN configuration). If your router's IP address is 192.168.1.1 you can access this page here: http://192.168.1.1/Vlan.asp

In this image, the bridge is called 'LAN'. As you can see, the VLAN configuration assigns the physical (switch) ports to VLAN 1 and ties them to the bridge 'LAN'. It assigns the wifi port to VLAN 2, and also ties it to the bridge 'LAN'.

Although it won't help you with this current issue,  if you are curious about things you can do with VLANs on dd-wrt, see this [site](https://www.flashrouters.com/blog/2015/04/06/what-is-a-vlan-how-to-setup-vlan-ddwrt/).

[image]

**Alternatives**

If the VLAN configuration wasn't setup incorrectly, or changing it's settings did not address the issue, then the next best option is the nuclear one. I would reset the router to the dd-wrt firmware's default values.

The reason I suggest a reset rather than digging deeper into other potential causes is that I can't think of a highly likely number 2 possible cause, and there are many, many things that could cause this - some visible from the web gui, some that would require interacting with the router over ssh. It will almost certainly be quicker to reset and reconfigure it than to track down the issue AND fix it.

Although there is a web gui method to reset the default settings, a hard reset is nearly always recommended over that method (I've heard various reasons - the gui reset doesn't work on all models, the code is buggy, etc.). Use this [Hard Reset](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Reset_And_Reboot#Hard_Reset_.28.2230_reset.22.29) method instead; this is the pertinent excerpt:

> **Hard Reset**
>   A hard reset sets the router back to the firmware's defaults, thus it
>   will clear all the settings you have configured in the router. Here
>   are some of the different ways that users are doing hard resets. Those
>   methods **will not unflash your router to the default firmware.** They
>   will reset to defaults such settings as IP address or password.
>   **After a hard reset the router will take a few minutes to boot**
>
> - Press and hold the button while the router is on, and keep holding it    about 30 seconds. On different models you may see rapid flashing
>     of    an LED, or a red error or diagnostic LED. Wait for it to return
>     to    normal operation (typically power-LED on solid). Normal
>     behaviour    here is for it to not actually clear the nvram, although
>     many people    think of it and phrase it that way. What it is supposed
>     to do is    return all settings to factory state, or to say it another
>     way, to    firmware defaults. If you added new non-factory variables
>     they should    still be there after this type of reset. One way of
>     tracking the    status of what's happening while holding in the reset
>     button is to    leave a network cable plugged in to your computer and
>     the router,    then watch the screen on your computer. After the
>     network has lost a    connection for the second time, the router is
>     usually reset back to    firmware defaults.

You will lose all customized configuration settings on the dd-wrt router if you do this - do not do this if you aren't comfortable reconfiguring the router (i.e. someone else set it up for you initially).

If you do reset the router, you should save a backup file of it's configuration so that next time you need to reset it, you can simply load a known good configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with dd-wrt on a Netgear Nighthawk R7000.
The suggestion provided by Argonauts gave me a clue.
Apparently the dd-wrt/R7000 did not like the Gigabit connection to my computer.
So... for the WIRED PORT to which the computer was connected on the R7000, I DISABLED (unchecked) the AUTO-NEGOTIATE and GIGABIT check-boxes.

I was then able to access the web-gui of dd-wrt; and continue with firmware update.